# Dotfuscator Root Check causes EncoderFallbackException in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, dotfuscator

I use PreEmptive Dotfuscator to obfuscate my Xamarin Forms app for Android platform. I was able to build app earlier, but same DotfuscatorConfig.xml started giving exception when I upgraded Windows to 10, VS to 2019 and used latest version of Dotfucator Community version.

**I am able to build successfully if I remove Root Check from DotfuscatorConfig.xml file.**

Below is the VS output with Exception details:

```
2>  Reflection call 'System.Type System.Type::GetType(System.String)' inside 'System.Boolean PreEmptive.SoS.Runtime.XRFinder::XRFind()' was detected with type name `䌏欑朓戕紗眙㈛嬝丟吡䴣吥䜧䐩䄫䬭帯䘱` which can't be resolved. (TaskId:285)
2>  Reflection call 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo System.Type::GetMethod(System.String,System.Type[])' inside 'System.Boolean PreEmptive.SoS.Runtime.XRFinder::XRFind()' does not use detectable instance type extraction (TaskId:285)
2>  Reflection call 'System.Type System.Type::GetType(System.String)' inside 'System.Boolean PreEmptive.SoS.Runtime.XRFinder::XRFind()' was detected with type name `䌏欑朓戕紗眙㈛圝漟డ琣䜥尧䈩` which can't be resolved. (TaskId:285)
2>  Reflection call 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo System.Type::GetMethod(System.String,System.Type[])' inside 'System.Boolean PreEmptive.SoS.Runtime.XRFinder::XRFind()' does not use detectable instance type extraction (TaskId:285)
2>  Reflection call 'System.Type System.Type::GetType(System.String)' inside 'System.Boolean PreEmptive.SoS.Runtime.XRFinder::XRFind()' was detected with type name `䌏欑朓戕紗眙㈛圝漟డ戣伥䐧伩` which can't be resolved. (TaskId:285)
2>  Reflection call 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo System.Type::GetMethod(System.String,System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' inside 'System.Boolean PreEmptive.SoS.Runtime.XRFinder::XRFind()' does not use detectable instance type extraction (TaskId:285)
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166: Child node "2" exited prematurely. Shutting down. Diagnostic information may be found in files in "C:\Users\WinUser\AppData\Local\Temp\" and will be named MSBuild_*.failure.txt. This location can be changed by setting the MSBUILDDEBUGPATH environment variable to a different directory.
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166: C:\Users\WinUser\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuild_pid-1412_8a13e9d544e74c94b378a56e64d81b58.failure.txt:
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166: UNHANDLED EXCEPTIONS FROM PROCESS 1412:
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166: =====================
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166: 7/9/2020 11:46:12 AM
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166: System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate Unicode character \uDDA3 at index 235 to specified code page.
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166:    at System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Char charUnknown, Int32 index)
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166:    at System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Char ch, Char*& chars)
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166:    at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(Char* chars, Int32 count, EncoderNLS baseEncoder)
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166:    at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(String chars)
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166:    at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166:    at Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventArgs.WriteToStream(BinaryWriter writer)
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166:    at Microsoft.Build.Framework.LazyFormattedBuildEventArgs.WriteToStream(BinaryWriter writer)
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166:    at Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildMessageEventArgs.WriteToStream(BinaryWriter writer)
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166:    at Microsoft.Build.Shared.LogMessagePacketBase.WriteToStream(ITranslator translator)
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166:    at Microsoft.Build.Shared.LogMessagePacketBase.Translate(ITranslator translator)
2>MSBUILD : error MSB4166:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeEndpointOutOfProcBase.RunReadLoop(Stream localReadPipe, Stream localWritePipe, ConcurrentQueue`1 localPacketQueue, AutoResetEvent localPacketAvailable, AutoResetEvent localTerminatePacketPump)
```

You must notice the Chinese characters in the initial logs - I wonder if it is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am on the Dotfuscator team and am answering in that capacity.

This looks to be a new issue introduced by a recent update to the Xamarin Android linker. We're investigating internally, but for now, you can disable the linker:

1. In Visual Studio, right-click your Android project in Solution Explorer and select *Properties*.
2. Go to *Android Options*.
3. Scroll down to *Linker properties*.
4. In the *Linking* drop-down, select *None*.

(The equivalent MSBuild property is `AndroidLinkMode`, set to `None`.)

If you build with this setting, you should be able to inject Root Checks again.

**UPDATE**: We've [filed an issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4909) with the Xamarin linker team about this. Thanks again for bringing it to our attention.